# OWEBIA - Magento 2.4 - setup global variable for all methods

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.4

is there a way to set up variable on top of list of methods?

I setup a function (return bool) looking for a custom attribute > OK
I display or hide each method on it > OK

exemple on one method :

```
//check if dangerous products
$allItems = $request->all_items;
$hasDangerousProduct = function ($allItems) use ($request) {
        $count = count(array_filter($allItems, function ($item) {
                                        return $item->product->dangerous_product == true;
                                    }
                )
            );
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

// France Relais Colis
addMethod('id_1', [
    'title'         => "Relais Colis",
    'enabled'       => in_array($request->dest_country_id, ['FR']) && $hasDangerousProduct($allItems) == false,
    'price'         => array_reduce([ [0,0.5,5.8], [0.51,1,6], [1.01,2,6.66], [2.01,3,6.95], [3.01,4,7.5], [4.01,5,8.10], [5.01,6,8.5], [6.01,7,8.72], [7.01,8,9.23], [8.01,9,9.9], [9.01,10,11], [10.01,11,12], [11.01,12,13], [12.01,13,13.5], [13.01,14,14], [14.01,15,15], [15.01,16,16], [16.01,17,17], [17.01,18,18] ], function ($carry, $item) use ($request) {
            if (isset($carry)) return $carry;
            if (isset($item[0]) && ($request->package_weight >= $item[0] && $request->package_weight <= $item[1])) {
               $carry = $item[2];
            }
            return $carry;
        }),
    'description'   => ""

])
->set('delivery_delay', 2);
```

I need to display a message if at least one method has been hidden depending on my function returning bool. Or If you prefer if this function return false, I have to display a message.

My idea is to get this result with ko and make my render template dynamic with it, but how to get a global information above shipping methids defined by Owebia ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Super naive option: at the end of your code

`if ($hasDangerousProduct()) {addError('Some options are not available as your order contains restricted products');}`

but of course you have no control over the look of the message and I haven't checked how translations might work.

Another "simple" way I might do it is to pass that information back up in all the methods - like you have `->set('delivery_delay', 2)` you could also set `hasDangerousProduct`

This is stuck in the shippingmethod information rather than at a wider scope but it should be possible to use it to trigger showing a message in the knockout code?

Comment: Ho, txs for your reply!!  This is exactly what I've done : option 2 > set hasDangerousProduct to all methods then loop in ko to set up local template boolean to manage my display... Not very sexy, but efficient ^^